# How to push to the Git repository after git clone?

Tags: git, github

I used `git clone -b branchname` to fetch the code from the Git. And then I modified my code. After that, I use `git push origin branchname` in order to push my code. But the GitBash does not allow me to do so because there is a conflict between my code and the Git repository. Some posts on the stackoverflow said that the command `git push -u "branchname"` could solve the issue. But, the conflict still exists after I tried. How can I solve my issue?

Besides, if I want to git one branch from the git repository and then updated another existing branch on the git repository, what can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make it clear - did you *commit* your changes?

Comment: try to make the question a little more clear, what is the case? what did you execute/change after cloning the repo? what is the error message provided by git?..etc